# Sending keystrokes to a browser window in python

Tags: python, browser, keystrokes

I need to send keystrokes to a inactive browser window using python.

I've tried using win32 module, but it doesn't work. It works in notepad but not the browser window.

Hopefully something simple and Pythonic, but at this point, I'm willing to try anything that can make my browser type buttons. TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Try using pexpect: https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

It can both capture and send keystrokes, plus it is pure python!